# Alt+Enter stopped working for Dart files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

When building Flutter apps the `ALT + Enter` keyboard shortcut is very convenient not only to bring up Quick Fixes but also to bring up a popup menu to wrap/remove Widgets. It was working fine until I ran `flutter upgrade` and updated the Dart and Flutter plugins in IntelliJ (version `2018.3.5`).

I have tried messing about with the keyboard shortcuts for an hour, disabling and re-enabling Dart/Flutter plugins, restarting and invalidating caches in IntelliJ, closing all other applications and rebooting Windows 10 numerous times. Nothing works. I can not get `Alt+Enter` to do anything anymore. It was working fine until I updated the plugins and the Flutter SDK, so it seems something in those updates broke it.

Actually, `Alt+Enter` doesn't seem to work for anything, and the "suggestion bulb" does not show up either. For example, if I type

```
String x  = 2;
```

the `2` gets the normal red underline, but no bulb shows up and `Al+Enter` does nothing. I've trippel checked that the "show intention bulb" is checked in the settings and that the correct keyboard shortcuts are assigned (just to be sure I have reset them to Default).

Has anyone else experienced this lately and found a fix? I've tried all the suggestions I could find on StackOverflow, but none of them work and none of them specifically target the Dart/Flutter intention/action/quickfix popup.

**EDIT**

This is the IntelliJ log after restarting. I started with the Dart SDK that seems to break Alt+Enter, then switched to the other one which makes Alt+Enter work but disables the possibility to select a device to run the app on, then switched back to the first one again (see comments near the end of the log):

```
// Startup with SDK C:\Users\MyUser\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk   2.2.0-edge.0a7dcf17eb5f2450480527d6ad1e201fb47f1e36
2019-03-04 10:10:01,523 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-183.5912.21, 26 Feb 2019 12:01) 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b28 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.152-b28 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2018.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\MyUser\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\MyUser\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\jre64\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,539 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=Cp1252 file=Cp1252 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,570 [     47]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 31 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,570 [     47]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2019-03-04 10:10:01,648 [    125]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2019-03-04 10:10:02,460 [    937]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor javaee-specific.xml 
2019-03-04 10:10:02,460 [    937]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor java-specific.xml 
2019-03-04 10:10:02,915 [   1392]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@6865c311[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@21227af0 
2019-03-04 10:10:02,931 [   1408]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.0 (JRE-managed HiDPI) 
2019-03-04 10:10:03,151 [   1628]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor javaee-specific.xml 
2019-03-04 10:10:03,151 [   1628]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor java-specific.xml 
2019-03-04 10:10:03,508 [   1985]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 138 plugins initialized in 451 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:03,508 [   1985]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), Android Support (10.3.1.2), AngularJS (183.5912.21), Ant Support (1.0), Application Servers View (0.2.0), AspectJ Support (1.2), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CFML Support (3.53), CSS Support (183.5912.21), CVS Integration (11), Cloud Foundry integration (1.0), CloudBees integration (1.0), CoffeeScript (183.5912.21), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (183.5912.21), Cucumber for Groovy (183.5912.21), Cucumber for Java (183.5912.21), DSM Analysis (1.0.0), Database Tools and SQL (183.5912.21), Docker integration (183.5912.21), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (183.5912.21), Emma (183.5912.21), Flash/Flex Support (183.5912.21), FreeMarker support (1.0), GWT Support (1.0), Geronimo Integration (1.0), Gherkin (999.999), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (183.5912.21), GlassFish Integration (1.0), Google App Engine (1.1.4), Gradle (183.5912.21), Grails (9.0), Groovy (9.0), Guice (8.0), HTML Tools (2.0), HTTP Client (183.5912.21), Haml (183.5912.21), Heroku integration (183.5912.21), Hibernate Support (1.0), I18n for Java (183.5912.21), IDE Settings Sync (183.5912.21), IDEA CORE (183.5912.21), IntelliJ Configuration Script (183.5912.21), IntelliLang (8.0), J2ME (1.0), JBoss Arquillian Support (1.0), JBoss Drools Support (1.0), JBoss Frameworks Base Support (1.0), JBoss Integration (1.0), JBoss Seam Pageflow Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Pages Support (1.0), JBoss Seam Support (1.0), JBoss jBPM (2.0.0), JSR45 Integration (1.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (183.5912.21), Java EE: Batch Applications (1.0), Java EE: Bean Validation Support (1.1), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency Injection (1.1), Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets (1.0), Java EE: JMS, JSON Processing, Concurrency, Transaction  (1.0), Java EE: Java Server Faces (2.2.X.), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (1.0), Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS) (1.9), Java EE: WebSockets (1.0), Java Server Pages (JSP) Integration (1.0), Java Stream Debugger (183.5912.21), JavaFX (1.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), Jetty Integration (1.0), Less support (183.5912.21), Markdown support (183.5912.21), Maven Integration (183.5912.21), Maven Integration Extension (183.5912.21), Mercurial Integration (10.0), OpenShift integration (1.0), Osmorc (1.4.12), Perforce Integration (2.0), Performance Testing (183.5912.21), Persistence Frameworks Support (1.0), Playframework Support (1.0), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (183.5912.21), Reactor framework support (1.0), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (183.5912.21), Resin Integration (8.1), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Sass support (183.5912.21), Settings Repository (183.5912.21), Smali Support (1.0), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (1.0), Spring Batch (1.0), Spring Boot (1.0), Spring Data (1.0), Spring Integration Patterns (1.0), Spring MVC (1.0), Spring OSGi (1.0), Spring Security (1.0), Spring Support (1.0), Spring Web Flow (1.0), Spring Web Services (1.0), Spring WebSocket (1.0), Spy-js (183.5912.21), Struts 1.x (2.0), Struts 2 (1.0), Stylus support (999.999), Subversion Integration (1.1), TFS (999.999), Tapestry support (1.0), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), Thymeleaf (1.0), Time Tracking (1.0), Tomcat and TomEE Integration (1.0), UI Designer (183.5912.21), UML Support (1.0), Vaadin Support (1.0), Velocity support (1.0), W3C Validators (2.0), WSL Support Framework (183.5912.21), WebLogic Integration (1.0), WebSphere Integration (1.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (183.5912.21), ZKM-Unscramble (1.0), dmServer Support (0.9.5), tslint (183.5912.21) 
2019-03-04 10:10:03,508 [   1985]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Dart (183.5912.23), Flutter (33.3.2), Kotlin (1.3.21-release-IJ2018.3-1), PHP (183.5429.47) 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,817 [   3294]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,892 [   3369]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,892 [   3369]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   git.explicit.commit.renames.prohibit.multiple.calls = false 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,905 [   3382]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Experimental features enabled for user: inline.browse.button 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,940 [   3417]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2019-03-04 10:10:04,997 [   3474]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,007 [   3484]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,287 [   3764]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=0.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,708 [   4185]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,724 [   4201]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,775 [   4252]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,901 [   4378]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 209 ms spent to cache options in application 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,901 [   4378]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity took 207 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,935 [   4412]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:122, number of extensions:100 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,942 [   4419]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:6 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,975 [   4452]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:24, number of extensions:135 
2019-03-04 10:10:05,975 [   4452]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2019-03-04 10:10:06,349 [   4826]   INFO - ndex.PrebuiltIndexProviderBase - Using prebuilt id-index from C:\Users\MyUser\.IntelliJIdea2018.3\system\index\.persistent\prebuilt\PHP\id-index.input 
2019-03-04 10:10:06,696 [   5173]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 94 application components initialized in 3639ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:06,697 [   5174]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 5993 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:06,963 [   5440]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - OS doesn't support touchbar, skip nst loading 
2019-03-04 10:10:07,455 [   5932]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1513 
2019-03-04 10:10:07,628 [   6105]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:171 
2019-03-04 10:10:07,796 [   6273]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2019-03-04 10:10:07,797 [   6274]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=16, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=16, fontScale=1.0 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,017 [   6494]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,017 [   6494]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [D:/FAPPS/ResursAppFlutter] 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,586 [   7063]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 200 project components initialized in 1429 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,664 [   7141]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 2766 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,763 [   7240]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 177 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:08,893 [   7370]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,023 [   7500]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,117 [   7594]   INFO - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,743 [   8220]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,787 [   8264]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,946 [   8423]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 24 project components initialized in 16 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:09,946 [   8423]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 1289 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,287 [   8764]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio 3.3/jre/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,334 [   8811]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,334 [   8811]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,334 [   8811]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,586 [   9063]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 632 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,602 [   9079]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 10 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:10,945 [   9422]   INFO - llij.database.util.SqlDialects - SQL dialects initialized in 78 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:11,678 [  10155]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 924ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:10:12,569 [  11046]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio 3.3/jre/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 
2019-03-04 10:10:12,616 [  11093]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2019-03-04 10:10:12,616 [  11093]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2019-03-04 10:10:12,616 [  11093]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2019-03-04 10:10:14,417 [  12894]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OpenFilesActivity run in 3550ms under project opening modal progress 
2019-03-04 10:10:14,502 [  12979]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Loaded external projects data in 9 millis 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,022 [  13499]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - DartDumbAwareStartupActivity run in 333ms under project opening modal progress 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,033 [  13510]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 4353ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 3/5 sluggish 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,099 [  13576]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Start.updateInitStatus === 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,103 [  13580]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.update create === 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,104 [  13581]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus === 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,471 [  13948]   INFO - .cloudConfig.CloudConfigClient - === Get cloud config URL: https://cloudconfig.jetbrains.com/cloudconfig/files === 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,486 [  13963]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 270 ms spent on EDT to cache options in application 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,843 [  14320]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus.value: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,848 [  14325]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 4170ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 3/4 sluggish 
2019-03-04 10:10:15,873 [  14350]   INFO - Json.PackageJsonUpdateNotifier - processPackageJsonFiles [] 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,746 [  15223]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - D:/FAPPS/ResursAppFlutter/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,767 [  15244]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,864 [  15341]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.20.1.windows.1 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,892 [  15369]   INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe : 2.20.1 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,951 [  15428]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateInitStatus === 
2019-03-04 10:10:16,987 [  15464]   INFO - lutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #1: C:/Users/MyUser/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,202 [  15679]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [D:/FAPPS/ResursAppFlutter] 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,240 [  15717]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 220 ms spent to cache options in project 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,240 [  15717]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to do them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,240 [  15717]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activity run in 220ms on UI thread 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,261 [  15738]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,339 [  15816]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar.start another widget: com.intellij.cloudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager$InfoComponent@2604d2f0 === 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,455 [  15932]   INFO - #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterCommand - C:\Users\MyUser\flutter\bin\flutter.bat [--no-color, config, --machine] 
2019-03-04 10:10:17,460 [  15937]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - Calling config --machine 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,028 [  17505]   INFO -     #io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk - flutter config --machine: 1568ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,105 [  17582]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 12018 ms 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,273 [  17750]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,579 [  18056]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 135 ms spent on EDT to cache options in project 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,901 [  18378]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 7ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:10:19,965 [  18442]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 64ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:10:20,618 [  19095]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - CreateKotlinSdkActivity run in 444ms on UI thread 
2019-03-04 10:10:43,936 [  42413]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting 

// Switched to C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk    2.1.0
2019-03-04 10:11:04,852 [  63329]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-03-04 10:11:04,950 [  63427]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 51ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:11:05,027 [  63504]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 77ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:11:05,069 [  63546]   INFO - lutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - shutting down Flutter device daemon #1: C:/Users/MyUser/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon 
2019-03-04 10:11:06,653 [  65130]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class io.flutter.sdk.FlutterPluginLibraryProperties 
2019-03-04 10:11:31,565 [  90042]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting 

// Switched back to C:\Users\MyUser\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk   2.2.0-edge.0a7dcf17eb5f2450480527d6ad1e201fb47f1e36
2019-03-04 10:12:04,384 [ 122861]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-03-04 10:12:04,560 [ 123037]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 42ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:12:04,612 [ 123089]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 52ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-03-04 10:12:04,820 [ 123297]   INFO - lutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #2: C:/Users/MyUser/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon 
2019-03-04 10:12:04,948 [ 123425]   INFO - lutter.run.daemon.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #3: C:/Users/MyUser/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon 
2019-03-04 10:12:16,621 [ 135098]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

Comment: Deleting `~/.dartServer/.analysis-driver/` might be worth a try.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the file type association still correct? Since intentions are based on the context / type...

Comment: I tried deleting the `.analysis-driver` folder, but it didn't seem to have any effect. However, I noticed that in the `Languages and frameworks -> Dart` settings in IntelliJ, the Dart SDK was set to `C:\Users\MyUsername\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk` (version `2.2.0-edge.xxxxxxxxxxx`). There was another SDK in the dropdown, `C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk` (version `2.1.0`) as well. When I chose the `2.1.0` SDK, things immediately started working normally. Not sure how that setting was changed, if it has been like that before or if the update did it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that selecting the non-Flutter Dart SDK also has the side effect of removing the ability to launch the app (or at least the emulator dropdown disappears).

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov See my edit.

Comment: Please check it with clean installation (without importing settings) of 2019.1 Beta: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: @y.bedrov Tried it, still nothing happens for Alt+Enter. I noticed that (in the old stable version of IntelliJ) Alt+Enter does work for things that are underlined with a gray line (typos), but not for red underlined problems and Flutter widgets. I also get the intent action "Suppress 'missing_required_param' warning" when doing Alt+Enter for widgets that miss required params. But that's the only option in the popupmenu.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution by now @MagnusW? I seem to have the same problem...

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I didn't find a solution, I'm still doing things manually... the problem persists after uninstalling+reinstalling IntelliJ and doing a Flutter upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @suffi I found a solution! See my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I imported another Flutter project I noticed that Alt+Enter was working fine in that project, but still not in the original project. I tried deleting all IntelliJ-related files (`*.iml` and `.idea` specifically) and recreating the original project - but Alt+Enter still didn't work.

That's when I started looking more carefully into the files in the `lib` source folder, and I found a suspicious file called `analysis_options.yaml` that I hadn't really noticed before. It contains

```
analyzer:
    language:
        enableSuperMixins: true
```

I deleted it (and the IntelliJ-related `*.iml` files and the `.idea` folder) and recreated the project - and finally Alt+Enter is working normally again!

The `analysis_options.yaml` file seems to have been added by a colleague a long time ago, so I'm still not sure why this problem didn't appear until after working on the project for a few months.

Comment: Even stranger in my case the contents of this file were commented out so they weren't being used. It's probably some bug. Remember to restart Android Studio if just deleting the file doesn't help.

Answer (score 28):

Here it is. You are welcome. 
[image]

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. At least on my IntelliJ installation, if the `analysis_options.yaml` file I mentioned in my answer exists, ALT+Enter stops working. This setting does not help in this case. You are welcome ;)

Comment: Great, but many other people coming to this post are not warned about the point that I mentioned. So, I don't think the downvote was necessary. https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2448#issuecomment-401527661

Comment: you are life saver!

Answer (score 22):

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Intentions` and **Confirm the `Dart Analysis Server`**.

**For Mac OS:**
Go to Android Studio -> `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Intentions` ->  Quick assists powered by the `Dart Analysis Server` (Mark it) -> **Apply**.

[image]

Comment: It is checked, but still Alt+Enter not suggesting to import libraries.

Comment: This happens to me also in some moments, and most of the time it is just a bug in the IDE, see if restarting your pc this error activated. Grateful and I hope you can solve it!

Comment: This is working. From where did you figure out ? :)

Comment: @ZumryMohamed After hours fiddling with Android Studio hahah

Comment: amazing bro, awesome bro, hahah

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 14):

Try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
Just to clarify, this option is in File -> Invalidate Chaches / Restart

Comment: `Invalidate Cache/ Restart` The solution to 90% of IntelliJ issues :)

Comment: Had the same problem after downgrading from Flutter 2 to Flutter 1.22.6 and `Invalidate and restart` helped get suggestions back.

Comment: this is work for me ty dude

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. This solved it for me:

1. Switch to a different flutter channel. If you are on stable then go to beta or vice versa. Instructions on switching channels at this link: 
   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading
2. Run `flutter upgrade`
3. Restart your IDE.
4. Check to see if the lightbulb (or ALT-Enter or Option-Return) is now active.
5. Switch back to your other channel and repeat steps 2 and 3 above.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are on Mac and nothing helps, try this:
[image]

Also, make sure that "Quick assist..." is checked (see @Gazihan Alankus's answer) and you have Dart and Flutter plugins installed on your Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

For someone that might still have this issue.
If you have tried all the above and it still doesn't work.

- Try disabling all your plugins and check if it has started working.
- If it starts working
- Enable your plugins one after the other to check for the plugin that made it not work

Answer (score 1):

If above solutions do not work, just remove project's .idea folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the shortcut of "Show Intention Actions" in the Keymap to see whether it's "Alt+Enter" or not. In my case, I'm using Mac OS X, Android Studio and the Eclipse Mac OS X keymap, and the shortcut of "Show Intention Actions" is "command+1".